# Does AWS Textract support Arabic text in a image file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ocr, arabic, uipath, amazon-textract

I need to do OCR on images that contain text in Arabic languages. I am using AWS Textract API in the python using UiPath

Does AWS Textract support the Arabic language?

Thanks in Advance.

I found many languages ,but I haven't seen the Arabic ,so does any anyone tried Textract in Arabic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [FAQ page](https://aws.amazon.com/textract/faqs/):

> • Make sure your document uses a language supported by Amazon Textract (currently English, Spanish, Italian, Portuguese, French and German; handwriting, invoices and receipts processing for English only).

Comment: How can I set the language of the file that will be read? For example, if I submit a file in Portuguese, how do I tell textract that I want it to try to recognize these characters in Portuguese?

Comment: You don't, as far as I know - it will detect the language automatically.